# How do I map facial motion capture markers to blend shape weights?

Tags: motion-capture

For shoestring budget facial motion capture, I can use [OpenCV](https://opencv.org/) or [Blender](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uNK8S19OSmA) to track sharpie dots on my face, but how do I then map that to blend shape weights of a game character that has a quite different facial structure? This sounds like an n-dimensional [natural neighbor interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_neighbor_interpolation) problem where n is number of dots times two. Is there any publicly available prior work the shoulders of which I can stand on? Or an *affordable* piece of software that I could use?